# $(this).attr('img') returned null or [object Object] not value

Tags: jquery

this is my problem. i am creating my own image popup in my site.

this is the script before the popup

```
<script> clicked = $('#gatb-1').click(function() { 
  return this.getAttribute('imid') }); </script>
```

*note: *clicked* is the global variable

this is the picture code:

```
<?php foreach ($the_picture as $picture) : ?>
<a id="gatb-1" imid="http://somesite.com/img/image.jpg" class="glr">
<div class="picture">
<img src="http://somesite.com/img/image.jpg" width="340px">
</div>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

then the  popup code is called below the picture code, this is the script when the popup display:block

this is the popup div:

```
<div class="popup">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#thmg').attr('src', clicked); }); 
</script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>left link</td>
<td><div class="picts"><img id="thmg" src="target here"></div></td>
<td>Right link</td>
</table>
</div>
```

i had also tried this code before the popup, but it is the same. always return the [object Object] or returned null

```
$(this).attr('imid')
```

the result is like this:

```
<img src="[object object]">
```

so, how can i pass the attribute? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Other than creating invalid HTML?

Comment: This makes no sense, you have an img attribute in the anchor, you don't close functions, you're basically doing everything wrong with invalid HTML, strange javascript stuff returning an img attribute to a global (does'nt work by the way) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found it! its not about the false code or anything.
its just because of the `<script></script>` is different global. its because i have the `<script></script>` in two places on 1 file.

```
<script> 
 clicked = $('#gatb-1').click(function() { 
  return this.getAttribute('imid') }); 
</script>
```

then access the variable in another  `<script></script>` is the one that's making it not to work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
       $('#thmg').attr('src', clicked);
});
</script>
```

so, the solution is, combine all the JQuery in one `<script></script>` only.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#gatb-1').click( function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr('imid');
    $('#thmg').attr('src', clicked);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me...

```
var img = $("#gatb-1").attr('img');
$("#thmg").attr('src', img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/Srx55/

Comment: thanks. but still I've got an [object object] value at src="" is it because of the loop on the image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assigning `$('#gatb-1')` to `clicked` instead of it's img attribute. If you're going to use that code (I wouldn't encourage it), `$('#thmg').attr('src', clicked.attr('img'))` would probably work

Comment: thanks, but     $('#thmg').attr('src', clicked.attr('img')) '  will have to pass to which variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<script> clicked = $('#gatb-1').click(function() { 
 return this.getAttribute('img') }); </script>
```

to

```
 <script> $('#gatb-1').click(function() { 
 clicked = $(this).attr('img') }); </script>
```

Comment: i have tried to use this style, but it gives me a blank output like this <img src="">